# Passing getActivity() with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I have created my own search view as below

```
public class MySearchView extends SearchView {

    public MySearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // The normal SearchView doesn't clear its search text when
    // collapsed, so we will do this for it.
    @Override
    public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
        setQuery("", false);
        super.onActionViewCollapsed();
    }
}
```

When i have to create an item of this search View i must pass the context like getActivity()

But since ActionBarActivity does not have getActivity(), what should I pass

Comment: Doesn't ActionBarActivity extend Activity?

Comment: how do I pass a context, there is no getActivity() method

Comment: use -> `this`, ActionBarActivity extends Activity that is a Context

Comment: Use MainActivity.this or getApplication()

Answer (score 2):

Inside the ActionBarActivity extended class, you can access the context by calling the method: getApplicationContext().

Hope this helps!
Nick